# Undefined method in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've binded all of my methods in the constructor to my class.
One of them is not working properly, the console logs an undefined error. It is executed in a function, but I previously declared it's this keyword as a class. I can not spot the problem. The **handleRemove** is the method, I'm talking about.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class ToDoList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {list: [], items: ''};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(ToDoList);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({items: event.target.value})
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    this.setState({ list: [...this.state.list, this.state.items]})
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  handleRemove(event) {
    const filteredArray = this.state.list.filter(item => item !== event.target.value)
    this.setState({list: filteredArray});
  }



  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input onClick={this.handleSubmit}type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
      <ul>
        {this.state.list.map(function(i, index){
          return(
            <li key={index}>{i}<button onClick={this.handleRemove}>X</button></li>
          )
        })}
      </ul>
      <p>Remaining: {this.state.list.length}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ToDoList;
```

Comment: this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(ToDoList); should be  this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting an undefined object property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

First, in your constructor, bind `this` and not `ToDoList`.

```
this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
```

Second, `functions` are scoped, so inside the `.map` `this` is not the component. You can fix that by using an arrow function (or alternatively using `.bind(this)`):

```
{this.state.list.map((i, index) => (
  <li key={index}>{i}<button onClick={this.handleRemove}>X</button></li>
))}
```

Comment: Thx Fabian, I just experimented with the this in the constructor and accidentally left the class as the this keyword, but now, it's working, I did not know about that the arrow functions will not create their own execution context.

Comment: Yes, it should work initially with the class name but you won't be able to delete a task. If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are binding the method to the `class`, not the `instance` - the class does not have a `static` method named `handleRemove`, and even if it did - you can not access `this` within a static method; therefore this will not work:

```
this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(ToDoList);
```

Change to:

```
this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
```